# T-SQL - CAST char with leading zeros to int

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting

I'd like to convert char with leading zeros to int, ex `'00010'` to `00010`. I've tried to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` :

```
select CONVERT(int, '00010')
```

but the function removes zeros at the beginning and return `10` instead of `00010`.
Do you know any easy solution to this? The length of input will be allways 5.

Comment: An `int` cannot have leading zeroes.

Comment: As HoneyBadger said. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Take special care to find out whether your input data is "5 digits" or "an integer that happens to always be presented with 5 digits". That is, if no arithmetic is ever performed on those 5 digits, converting them to an `INT` may be a worthwhile optimization, or it might be a mistake that'll cause you grief if concatenating those 5 digits to something else is the most common operation, and it should have just remained as a `CHAR(5)`. (I've had experience with a system that improperly chopped up digit strings as integers this way; it can actually lead to data loss.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, leading zeros are meaningless, so an `Int` can't have leading zeros.

If you need to display leading zeroes, you can always convert to `varchar` and use concatenation with `right`, like this:

```
DECLARE @MyVal int = 10;
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CAST(@MyVal as varchar(5)), 5)
```

Comment: This is a commonly used approach, I know... But it's dangerous, if the numbers might exceed the given count. I prefer `REPLACE(STR(@MyVal,5),' ','0')`. This would return `*****` instead of a wrong number...

Comment: @Shnugo You've got me thinking... [take a look at this.](http://rextester.com/BEIG57523) Turns out the commonly used approach is not so bad after all :-)

Comment: Yeah, with the correct length in `VARCHAR(X)` this is fine. Quite often you'd see a number to high in this place (thus returning wrong results). I prefer my approach due to another reason too: You have to specify the lenght in one place only. Easy to parameterize... The approach above needs the `5` in two places and a fitting count of `0` in a third place. At the end it's a matter of taste... (and to be honest: It's not an answer to the question actually :-D)

Comment: This behavior was "fixed" for the Unicode types -- a `CAST` to an `N[VAR]CHAR` that won't fit yields an overflow error rather than `*`. In fact, *only* `INT`/`SMALLINT`/`TINYINT` casts to `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` will give this result, so while reliable (and documented as such), it's still legacy stuff that's a bit iffy. It all depends on how you would like your errors to be handled, I suppose.

Comment: @Shnugo well, the first sentence is an answer... However Jeroen had a valid point in his comment to the question - perhaps converting to int is the wrong thing to do anyway...

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your input. I seem to always learn something new when reading your comments...

Comment: Thank you, I've missed that `Int` can't have leading zeros. Will try to work with `VARCHAR` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You must read about data types. An `INT` is noting more than a bit pattern. Whenever you see the number in a human readable format, the actual value is translated to a string consisting of digits. But this digit format is not the actual `INT`.

Leading Zeros are never part of the `INT` itself, but may be added to the string representation. So your question (taken literally) does not make any sense actually.

If there is a string like `00012` and you want to use it like a number, you should just cast it:

```
SELECT CAST('00012' AS INT) + 2; --14
```

Other answers show you some approaches to get a padded string representation out of an `INT`, but this is the opposite direction:

```
SELECT REPLACE((STR(12,5),' ','0'); --00012
```

You can combine these approaches:

```
DECLARE @PaddedNumber CHAR(5)='00012'
SELECT REPLACE(STR(CAST(@PaddedNumber AS INT) + 2,5),' ','0'); --00014
```

The padded number (which is - by type! - a string) is casted to an `INT`, then used in computation. The result is an `INT`, which can be converted to a padded string. But the final result's type is string...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(INT,'00010'), 'd5')
```

should solve the problem :)

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but... Also, it's only working with 2012 or higher version.

Comment: OP states: *I'd like to convert char with leading zeros to int*. (This is senseless of course...). Your answer is not an answer to the question IMHO.